# How do I install OpenOffice instead of LibreOffice?

Tags: software-installation, openoffice.org

I want to install OpenOffice. What can I do to install it on my computer?

Comment: To anyone who wants to follow these instructions: Please remember that LibreOffice evolved from OpenOffice when it was dropped by it's original developers, so if you are looking for a full-featured Office software, LibreOffice should be enough for you. Not so long ago the original OpenOffice was picked up by Apache, so currently there is a fair choice between these two platforms, but LibreOffice is by no means "worse" or "less feature-packed". Therefore this question is useful for those who for some reasons want to replace the default software with LibreOffice, which does not differ a lot.

Answer (score 59):

**NOTE** - To remove LibreOffice *( to avoid any conflict)* please read [Rick Green's below answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/116592/63025) and then follow this.

---

Now it is known as **Apache OpenOffice** which is  available [through third Party repository](https://launchpad.net/~upubuntu-com/+archive/office) as

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/office 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openoffice
```

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

If you are on a 64 bit system you are not done yet.
Starting openoffice3 will fail with the message "no suitable windowing system found, exiting". You need to install some 32 bit libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libxrandr2:i386 libxinerama1:i386
```

Next, it fails with "exception in syncronize" because permissions are wrong. Fix them. Then it worked for me.

```
sudo chmod a+rx /opt/openoffice.org3/share/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages
```

---

#### Alternate method

Download `.tar.gz` from [here](http://www.openoffice.org/download/other.html) , selecting your Arch type through [Linux Intel DEB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/stable/3.4.0/Apache_OpenOffice_incubating_3.4.0_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz/download) for 32-bit and [Linux x86-64 DEB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/stable/3.4.0/Apache_OpenOffice_incubating_3.4.0_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz/download) for 64-bit, it basically contains `.deb installation packages`. Follow these instructions:

- Unpack the downloaded `Apache_OpenOffice_incubating_3.4.0_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz` to prepare for installation by

  ```
  tar -xvzf Apache_OpenOffice_incubating_3.4.0_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz
  ```

  The Extracted directory will be named after the Language you selected to download like

  `en-US`

  Navigate into `DEBS` folder

  Install the .deb files by typing

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i *.deb
  ```

By default, this will install Apache OpenOffice in your `/opt` directory.

For installing the desktop integration features for your setup navigate to `desktop-integration` in the `DEBS` installation directory and do

```
  sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

***NOTE*** Be careful ppa:upubuntu-com/office refers to older version of open office.

---

[SOURCE](http://www.openoffice.org/download/common/instructions.html#linux-deb)

---

[Linked answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298781/how-can-i-install-openoffice)

Comment: This does **not** include a recommendation to *first remove* LibreOffice. These two packages are very similar and may not work together.

Comment: @david6- The question wasn't asked in that context anyhow, good point though , but that's up-to User's choice. I will link [above Rick Green's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/116592/63025) to include it too.

Comment: For me, 12.04 and method #1 doesn't work. Seems to be conflict or confusion with Java - this appears to be effecting more than a few people: https://www.google.co.za/search?q=javaldx%3A+Could+not+find+a+Java+Runtime+Environment!+ubuntu+12.04&oq=javaldx%3A+Could+not+find+a+Java+Runtime+Environment!+ubuntu+12.04 ... ubuntuforum advice didn't fix it: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12223047&postcount=8, and seems there're related bugs, but not enough caring: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/926594. That being said, method #2 worked great, so thanks to tijybba.

Comment: In my case the server didn't have "unzip" installed so it silently failed even though everything completed.

Comment: @Mondain - You don't need unzip to extract tar.gz file , use tar cmd as above or here http://askubuntu.com/a/25962/63025

Comment: The unzip was needed for method 1, as the post process will not run without it. But it is true that using tar would allow you to complete the un-tar part of the post proc. I actually found the "Alternative" method to work the best for me.

Comment: The first method no longer works. ppa is dead... Can we get an updated answer?

Comment: I could use the first method on 64 bit system without doing any of the steps given specifically for 64 bit system

Comment: I installed with the alternate method. Now where can i find its icon to open it.

Comment: `ppa:upubuntu-com/office` is broken for at least Ubuntu Trusty.

Comment: Installing a software in ubuntu is a tedious task, I'd rather die than using ubuntu.

Comment: Neither method works.

Comment: "E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/office/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found"

Answer (score 17):

1) For installing OpenOffice you have to first uninstall the LibreOffice which is by default installed in your Ubuntu.

So open the Terminal Window and type the following command and give password.This will remove the LibreOffice completely.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-core
```

(OR)

Open the Ubuntu Software Center and search for “LibreOffice core” and click on remove (uninstall).This will uninstall the LibreOffice completely.

2) Download [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) from its official website.The download file will be in *.tar.gz format.

3) After the file is downloaded, go to the downloaded directory and click on “Extract here”.

4) Now open the Terminal and change the directory to the location where your Extracted Open Office file is present.Just type “cd” followed by  drag and dropping the “DEBS” folder or manually do it.

5) Type the following command which will install OpenOffice by installing all the *.deb package files.

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

6) Enjoy using OpenOffice. The default installation location is /opt/openoffice4 and Apache OpenOffice executable is called *soffice* and is located in /opt/OpenOffice4/program/

[source](http://www.openoffice.org/download/common/instructions.html#linux)

Comment: Whenever I'm trying to do that, it's remove 'gnome' metapackage as-well "sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-core",              which in-turn is removing gnome packages like 'transmission' and many more. . . !

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*` if you still see any errors when installing open office.

Comment: Went through this answer step by step and it didn't work. It's not showing on the menu or when I search through the menu and running "soffice" from the terminal yields "/usr/bin/soffice: 175: exec: /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash: not found"