# How to install Openoffice?

Tags: 12.04, openoffice.org

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Open Office?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116590/how-to-install-open-office)

first of all. I have a question, that deals with OpenOffice suite/program. I am trying to figure out how to instal OpenOffice Suite. I went to the website and download and clicked linux the tar.gz file format. I downloaded it. I put the file in my home directory. I tried to install/extract it with the terminanal it work. But I don't see it on my desktop or with the hud.
  I have done some research toward doing it a differnt way but I don't trust the site. Click on the link on here, it seems safe but it's maybe just me. There are some website here they are

- http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/.../install-oracle-openoffice-33-from-ppa.html
- http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/05/how-to-install-apache-openoffice-34-via.html

  I you have any input toward how to do it install it / run it. I would appericate the help.