# Cannot re-install libreoffice after purge

Tags: installation, libreoffice, openoffice.org

I wanted to substitute the default LibreOffice by OpenOffice. To do so I followed the instructions on this link [How do I install OpenOffice instead of LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116590/how-do-i-install-openoffice-org-instead-of-libreoffice/116592#116592)

After doing it I didn't get OpenOffice to open any of my .odf files and now I don't have neither LibreOffice nor OpenOffice functioning. So now what I want to do is to install again LibreOffice, but both from the software center and the terminal an error message appears saying (sorry because the messages are in Catalan and I dont know how to get them in English):

(on the software center)

Els paquets següents tenen dependències sense satisfer:

libreoffice: Depends: fonts-sil-gentium-basic però no s'instal·larà
             Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:4.1.4~rc2-0ubuntu1~saucy1~ppa1) però 1:4.1.4~rc2-0ubuntu1~saucy1~ppa1 s'instal·larà
             Depends: fonts-dejavu però no s'instal·larà

(on the terminal)

```
joan@joan-VPCEA3S1E:~$ sudo apt-get install libreoffice
[sudo] password for joan: 
S'està llegint la llista de paquets… Fet 
S'està construint l'arbre de dependències       
S'està llegint la informació de l'estat… Fet
No s'han pogut instaŀlar alguns paquets. Això pot ser degut a que heu
demanat una situació impossible o que esteu emprant la distribució
«unstable» i alguns paquets requerits encara no han estat creats o bé
encara no els hi han introduït des d'«Incoming».
La informació següent pot ajudar-vos a resoldre la situació:

Els següents paquets tenen dependències sense satisfer:
 libreoffice : Depèn: fonts-sil-gentium-basic però no és instaŀlable
               Depèn: libreoffice-base però no serà instaŀlat
               Depèn: libreoffice-report-builder-bin però no serà instaŀlat
               Depèn: fonts-dejavu però no és instaŀlable
               Recomana: libreoffice-gnome però no serà instaŀlat o
                         libreoffice-kde però no serà instaŀlat
E: No es poden corregir els problemes, teniu paquets retinguts que estan trencats.
```

What can I do?

Comment: Using `sudo LANGUAGE=C command` should give you messages in English (C locale).

Comment: See if http://askubuntu.com/a/363244/16395 can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to uninstall LibreOffice and OpenOffice using Synaptic, from where you have to remove completelly all the related files (config files), reboot and then install LibreOffice from scratch again. Synaptic will fetch all the necessary files asked by LibreOffice.

Answer (score 1):

You had already installed the LibreOffice PPA (note the `1:4.1.4~rc2-0ubuntu1~saucy1~ppa1` in your error message). You then followed instructions for removing the standard LibreOffice package without also removing the PPA. This may have been the source of the problems you later experienced.

Make sure that you have purged OpenOffice: `sudo apt-get remove --purge <package_name>`. The package name may be `openoffice` as a metapackage, but you may need to check the .deb files you used when installing OpenOffice for the correct package names.

Once that is done, `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove any unneeded dependencies from OpenOffice.

The LibreOffice PPA looks like it is still in your sources list, so you can `sudo apt-get update` to rebuild the package lists so you get the packages needed by the PPA instead of the standard version of LibreOffice. If you need to reinstall the PPA, see the[LibreOffice PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa) for instructions on how to re-install it.

After that, you can install LibreOffice normally.

Answer (score 0):

Then try:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get -f install libreoffice
```

The first command will remove unused packages, the second will install libreoffice with the packages it needs.

I hope it works for you.