# How can I install Open Office?

Tags: openoffice.org

I have install Apache_OpenOffice_4.0.1_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz in ubuntu13.10 using tar.gz file but no errors, now I am not able to start the open office service. I don't find it in application also.

How can I install Open Office?

Comment: could this be what you are looking for: http://askubuntu.com/a/168013/476968 ?

Answer (score 0):

Extract that file with

```
tar -xvzf Apache_OpenOffice_4.0.1_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz
```

and then install .deb packages with

```
cd en-US/debs
dpkg -i *.deb
```

After that, you should be able to start it. If you want to enable desktop integrations (desktop shortcuts), also run

```
cd desktop-integrations
dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: Couple of things submitted as suggested edit - .tar.gz uses the -z switch rather than -j, and `openoffice.org` isn't a package in 13.10 (or at least, not without adding an extra repository somewhere) so that part isn't really relevant here.

Comment: Yep, you're correct on both counts. I rejected the edit as it removed parts detailing source code installation - that package do not contain compiled OO.org.

Comment: @JezW Aagh. I failed. Downloaded wrong file. So yeah, the suggested edit was perfectly fine. Sorry.

Comment: Huh. I looked at the edit history, don't remember snipping anything about source code, but it is right there in the original. Either I'm going mad, or I need more coffee. (Or quite possibly less). Anyway, no worries, what's two rep between friends? =)

Comment: Crazy things. But really, probably just simultaneous edits (both opened edit view before either saved it). SE doesn't warn about that, afaik.

Comment: @olli the question first says"how to open the installed openoffice".

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'm pretty much sure it says "How can I install Open Office?" on the last line.