# Installing OpenOffice

Tags: software-installation, deb

I am new to Ubuntu and I am attempting to install OpenOffice. (Libre Office does not recognise conditional formatting and hence the dependant macros in my OO spreadsheets) and I am not prepared to write new ones).

I get a load of deb files. I understand that a deb file opens by double clicking it but which one comes first as I always get a message " Dependency is not satisfiable: openoffice"

I am trying to move from XP for obvious reasons.

I am having the same problem with Google Earth.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, but no technical dissertations please I like to lead a simple life.

Comment: "I get a load of deb files". you get ONE deb file?! http://www.openoffice.org/download/other.html#aoo

Comment: What is the exact `.deb` file name and from where did you download it?

Comment: > Libre Office does not recognise conditional formatting How about `LibreOffice Calc Menu:Format > Conditional formatting > ...` ? ... but as you say, there might be issues with self-written **macros**.

Comment: A general comment - using ubuntu is much easier if you try to find the software in "Ubuntu Software Center" (USC for short at times). Next step in complexity is to use `apt-get` from the command lines instead, and possibly resort to custom sources designated by `PPA`'s - both these end up in the same database, and will have updates be easy on you.

Comment: There are too many files to type out there are 88 deb files.  Downloaded from sourceforge it seems that apache subcontract it to a third party - perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: http://www.openoffice.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

Open a command line (using `Ctrl+Alt+t`) navigate to that folder where all the .deb files are  ( `cd ~/Downloads/folder_name`) and there do a `sudo dpkg -i *openoffice*.deb` provide the user password and that should be all.

Comment: NOTE: Might be a good idea to have ONLY those *.deb files you're playing with, in there. Create a special folder.

Comment: ok let me change something. ok done.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed openoffice, and this is what I did:

First of all I removed libreoffice, to avoid conflicts:

```
sudo apt remove --purge libreoffice-*
```

At this point, I downloaded the package in my desktop (in my case, 64-bit architecture and Italian language it) from [here](http://www.openoffice.org/it/download/).
[image]

To install openoffice: first unpack the file with the command (**the file  version, architecture and language may be different**):

```
tar xvzf ~/Desktop/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.0_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_it.tar.gz
```

Now we are ready for installation (**Also here, the directory created corresponds to your language. In my case, it**):

```
cd it/DEBS
sudo dpkg-i *. deb
```

the last step, install the links in the menu:

```
cd desktop-integration
sudo dpkg-i *. deb
```

Now openoffice is installed.

References:

[apache download page](http://www.openoffice.org/download/common/instructions.html#linux-deb)
[askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116590/how-do-i-install-openoffice-org-instead-of-libreoffice)

Comment: So I followed these steps, but I can't find openoffice anywhere. I try typing it in from the home button, but the only results that show up are the tar ball file I downloaded, the deb files that were extracted and the openoffice4 folder inside the opt folder which I assume was created on installation. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit. What's going on here? Did openoffice install? How do I now open it? Thanks.