# Unable to install Acache Open office

Tags: software-installation

I know many have asked this question, but there seems to be a pertinent problem. 
I followed the instructions as given here 
[How do I install OpenOffice instead of LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116590/how-do-i-install-openoffice-org-instead-of-libreoffice)
But when I run the command `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` I get the following.

```
(Reading database ... 465930 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack openoffice4.1-debian-menus_4.1.1-9775_all.deb ...
Unpacking openoffice-debian-menus (4.1.1-9775) over (4.1.1-9775) ...
/usr/bin/gtk-update-icon-cache
gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.
/usr/bin/gtk-update-icon-cache
gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.
Setting up openoffice-debian-menus (4.1.1-9775) ...
/usr/bin/gtk-update-icon-cache
gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.
/usr/bin/gtk-update-icon-cache
gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.10.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
```

I have uninstalled Libre-office.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and can someone please help me install Open office?

Comment: I suggest you file a bug report upstream as this package is not in the ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen And how might I do that? I must apologise, I am very new to Ubuntu and I do not know my way around it yet.

Comment: https://www.openoffice.org/qa/issue_handling/pre_submission.html

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal:

Run it:

```
sudo -i
rm /usr/share/mime/packages/apacheopenoffice.xml 
update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```